# How can I compute the gradient of multiple outputs with respect to a batch of inputs in a single backward pass in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, backpropagation, multilabel-classification, autograd

I am performing multi-label image classification in PyTorch, and would like to compute the gradients of all outputs at ground truth labels for each input with respect to the input. I would preferably like to do this in a single backward pass for a batch of inputs.

For example:

```
inputs = torch.randn((4,3,224,224)) # Batch of 4 inputs
targets = torch.tensor([[1,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,0]]) # Labels for each input
outputs = model(inputs) # 4 x 3 vector
```

Here, I want to find the gradient of:

- `output[0,0]` and `output[0,2]` with respect to `input[0]`
- `output[1,0]` with respect to `input[1]`
- `output[2,2]` with respect to `input[2]`
- `output[3,0]` and `output[3,1]` with respect to `input[3]`

**Is there any way to do this in a single backward pass?**

---

If my outputs were one-hot, i.e., there was only one label per class, I could use:

```
gt_classes = torch.where(targets==1)[1]
gather_outputs = torch.gather(outputs, 1, gt_classes.unsqueeze(-1))
grads = torch.autograd.grad(torch.unbind(gather_outputs), inputs)[0] # 4 x 3 x 224 x 224
```

This gives gradient of `output[i,gt_classes[i]]` with respect to `input[i]`.

For my case, it looks like the `is_grads_batched` argument from `torch.autograd.grad` might be relevant, but it's not very clear how it is to be used.

Comment: Is it a batch size of `4` or do you mean `4d` input (`5d` with batch) i.e. `[b, 4, 3, 224, 224]`?

Comment: @WakemeUpNow The batch size is 4.

Comment: So in the forward pass, do each item in a batch interact with each other? If no then the gradient is `0`. Except for the corresponding index of course i.e. gradient of `output[0]` w.r.t. `input[0]` still exists, just not `output[0]` w.r.t `input[1]`

Comment: @WakemeUpNow No, they do not, and I realize I mislabeled the output indices in my question. Updating now. Thanks for pointing this out.